# Format NSDate from POSIX time in milliseconds

Tags: objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I've come across several answered questions how to populate an `NSDate` object from `POSIX` date time.  Unfortunately the examples were using `POSIX` time in `milliseconds`.  What about the string format of `POSIX` time, when I run the following code startDate = `nil`

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate *startDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"1970-01-17T02:31:52.44"];
NSLog(@"%@", startDate);
```

**SOLUTION:**

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SS"];
NSDate *startDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"1970-01-17T02:31:52.44"];
NSLog(@"%@", startDate);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your date formatter to this:

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SS"];
```

You need to add the miliseconds and escape the T

Comment: Thanks! That's the solution.